# Adobe Flash: Countdown Timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem about my code in my timer. I've made a movie clip and put this code in my first frame inside the movie clip:

```
if (time_txt.text ==0) {

this._parent.gotoAndPlay(5);

}
```

And I have this code in my 12th frame:

```
time_txt.text = Number (time_txt.text)-1;
gotoAndPlay(1);
```

Its in the 12th frame because im using 12 frames per second. And go to 5th frame in my first code because if the time is over the frame will go to the 5th frame in my main scene that has "times up" word. By the way this code is inside my movie clip, and the movie clip is inside my scene 1. By the way im making a game. And im using air for android for my file type. Thanks

Comment: Stop using timeline code, if you really want to make a game.

Comment: Sir can you teach me some codes for countdown timer and when the timer is on 00 it leads them to a specific frame. Because im having so much problem. Im making a game for my thesis. Thanyou

Comment: I double @philipp Before starting your first AIR game for Android there's quite a lot of things you need to learn first. Not mixing timeline frames and scripting is one of them.

Comment: Try to use a `main.as` class file, remove all timeline code, learn some AS3 and get familiar how the flash architecture is setup. Otherwise you will end up with spaghetti code, distributed over frames, a nightmare to debug and nearly impossible for anybody here to help you. Stop coding like that, take some time to learn first.

Comment: Yes, inline code is evil but in your case it might work if you change it to  (time_txt.text == "0") - text is a string, not integer

Comment: Try : **http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3timer/**